# Is there something like Map.keySet for a partial function in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, partialfunction

More specifically, I have:

```
case class Key (key: String)
abstract class abstr {
  type MethodMap = PartialFunction[Key,  String => Unit]
  def myMap: MethodMap // abstract

  def useIt (key: Key, value: String) = {
    val meth = myMap(key)
    meth(value)
  }

  def report = {
    for (key <- myMap.keySet) // how to do this
      println("I support "+key)
  }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
class concrete extends abstr {
  var one: Boolean
  def method1(v: String): Unit = ???
  def method2(v: String): Unit = ???

  def map1: MethodMap = {
    case Key("AAA") => method1
  }
  def map2: MethodMap = {
    case Key("AAA") => method2
  }

  override def myMap: MethodMap = if (one) map1 else map2
}
```

Of course, this is somewhat simplified, but the report function is necessary.

Some history: I first had it implemented using `Map` but then I changed it to `PartialFunction` in order to support the following `override def myMap: MethodMap = if (one) map1 else map2`.

Any suggestion to refactor my code to support everything is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `PartialFunction` can be defined (and often is) on infinite sets. E.g. what do you expect `report` to return in these situations:

```
class concrete2 extends abstr {
  def myMap = { case Key(_) => ??? }
}
```

or

```
class concrete2 extends abstr {
  def myMap = { case Key(key) if key.length > 3 => ??? }
}
```

? If you have a finite list of values you are interested in, you can do

```
abstract class abstr {
  type MethodMap = PartialFunction[Key,  String => Unit]
  def myMap: MethodMap // abstract
  val keys: Seq[Key] = ...

  def report = {
    for (key <- keys if myMap.isDefined(key))
      println("I support "+key)
  }
}
```

> Some history: I first had it implemented using Map but then I changed it to PartialFunction in order to support the last line in second part.

Why? This would work just as well with `Map`.

> In your solution, is there any way to define the domain of the partial function to be the finite set `keys`

```
def f: MethodMap = { case key if keys.contains(key) => ... }
```

Of course, the domain isn't part of the type.

Comment: In your solution, is there any way to define the domain of the partial function  to be the finite set `keys` instead of the more general type `Key`?

Comment: And this `if` will work just as well with `Map` (of course, you need to use the same type everywhere). Edited to answer your second comment.